# Text field looking option inside my select tag

Tags: html, css, html-select

I cannot seem to quite search for the correct term to solve my issue but, I have this weird text field like thing above my select list:

[image: 1]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group">
 <select class="form-control w-100 config_view_type">
 <option value="P">Public</option>
 <option value="R">Restricted</option>
 </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

what's causing it to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have positioned your form using css. Can you elaborate your code a bit more? I just placed your code inside a template and it seems to be working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The select element</h1>

<p>The select element is used to create a drop-down list.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  
   <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group">
 <select class="form-control w-100 config_view_type">
 <option value="P">Public</option>
 <option value="R">Restricted</option>
 </select>
 </div>
</div>
what's causing
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the 
server called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code Worked fine, maybe the issue with which bootstrap you linked the document with. try the bootstrap link I used

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control w-100 config_view_type">
      <option value="P">Public</option>
      <option value="R">Restricted</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```